# Returning screen name and count from JSON representation on twitter users in python

Tags: python, json, twitter

I'm trying to define a function that returns each user's screen name ('screen_name') and followers count ('followers_count') from a file that contains a json representation of a list of twitter users:

file example (shortened)`
(...)

```
"followers_count": 1815974, 
"follow_request_sent": false, 
"followers_count": 22928633, 
"screen_name": "twitterapi", 

"favourites_count": 22, 
"follow_request_sent": false, 
"followers_count": 22928633, 
"screen_name": "twitter",
```

(...)`

it should return something like this:

```
>>> followers_counts(open(input))
{u’twitter’: 22928633, u’twitterapi’: 1815974}
```

This is what I got so far, as you can see I'm not very good at this:

```
def followers_counts(input):
tweet = json.loads(input)
name = tweet["screen_name"]
count = tweet["followers_count"]
print "u '(1)':(2)".format(name, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your JSON file looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "followers_count": 1815974, 
        "follow_request_sent": false, 
        "followers_count": 22928633, 
        "screen_name": "twitterapi"
    },
    {
        "favourites_count": 22, 
        "follow_request_sent": false, 
        "followers_count": 22928633, 
        "screen_name": "twitter"
    }
]
```

...you would do something like this:

```
def followers_counts(input):
    users = json.loads(input)
    output = {}
    for user in users:
        output[user["screen_name"]] = user["follower_count"]
    return output
```

...and that would return a dict that looks like what you want. You can then use it, turn it into a string, or manipulate it however else you want.

You can also condense this function using dict comprehensions:

```
def followers_counts(input):
    return {user["screen_name"]: user["follower_count"] for user in json.loads(input)}
```